# Encrypted 16.04 boots to initramfs

Tags: boot, kernel

64 bit 16.04 Ubuntu on Toshiba C855 laptop  I'm still new to linux.

Suddenly can't boot to anything after encrypt sign in, instead I get a black screen reading as follows:

```
[   1.698476] EFI: Problem loading in-kernel X.509 certificate (-65)
[    2.269858] [drm: intel_cpu_fifo_underrun_irq_handler [i915]] *ERROR* CPU pipe A FIFO underrun
[    2.270428] [drm: intel_set_pch_fifo_underrun_reporting [i915]] *ERROR* uncleared pch fifo underrun on pch transcoder A
[    2.270483] [drm: intel_pch_fifo_underrun_irq_handler [i915]] *ERROR* PCH transcoder A FIFO underrun

BusyBox v1.22.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.22.0-15ubuntu1) built-in shell (ash)
Enter ‘help’ for a list of built-in commands

(initramfs) _
```

If I type in help I get the following:

### Built-in commands:

```
. : [ alias break cd chdir command continue echo eval exec exit
export false getopts hash help history let local printf pwd read 
readonly return set shift test times trap true type ulimit umask
unalias unset wait [ [[ acpid ash awk basename blockdev cat chmod
chroot chvt clear cmp cp cut deallocvt devmem df dnsdomainname
du dumpkmap echo egrep env expr false fbset fdflush fgrep find
fstrim grep gunzip gzip hostname hwclock ifconfig ip kill ln
loadfont loadkmap ls lzop lzopcat mkdir mkfifo mknod mkswap mktemp
modinfo more mount mv openvt pidof printf ps pwd readlink reset
switch_root sync tail tee test touch tr true tty umount uname 
uniq unlzop wc wget which yes zcat
(initramfs) _
```

Would appreciate any info anyone can give me. Thanks

Comment: You didn't by by chance disable secure boot in the BIOS did you?

Comment: Not knowingly, but there are other computers on the same wi fi including an iPhone logged into magic jack voip phone service. could any of these be causing the problem?

Comment: The magic jack is actually installed on a macbook, not the toshiba

Comment: I was able to get into bios and it shows the secure boot is enabled.

Comment: Well, I got to go to work. I'll check in again tomorrow. I hope that someone will answer by then with information that will tell me if it can be fixed or if it's gone for good.